# Tensorflow Lite Android GPU Delegate (C++) static build with bazel missing dependencies

Tags: android, c++, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I cloned the Tensorflow repository from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow

I configured bazel build system like 5th step in the link https://cppmagister.tistory.com/6

- NDK version 21.3.6528147
- SDK version 30.0.3

I build tensorflow with this command

```
bazel build -c opt --config android_arm64 tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu:delegate
```

There are 3 files

```
/tensorflow_src/bazel-out/arm64-v8a-opt/bin/tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/libdelegate.a
/tensorflow_src/bazel-out/arm64-v8a-opt/bin/tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/libdelegate.pic.a
/tensorflow_src/bazel-out/arm64-v8a-opt/bin/tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/libdelegate.so
```

I wanted to use static library so I added **libdelegate.a** to my project. I added headers from source. When I build the project I got an error like below.

```
external/com_google_absl/absl/container/internal/hashtablez_sampler.h:137: error: undefined reference to 'absl::lts_2020_02_25::container_internal::UnsampleSlow(absl::lts_2020_02_25::container_internal::HashtablezInfo*)'
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible libdelegate.a was linked against a SHARED dependency (in this case, ABSL?) and will include UNDEFINED symbols.

You can use the [linux program nm](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nm.1.html) to view the symbol table of the libraries.

I would use "nm -DC libdelegate.a" -- the C will demangle C++ symbols and the D will show dynamic symbols only.  If there are no dynamic symbols, just drop the D.

Symbols marked as "U" are undefined and will need to be provided by either another link step or loaded at runtime.